# jquery one table inherit height from another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two tables, with same amount of tr's. They are both loading dynamically and I can't merge them. Here's how they look like for example: [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/4pdCq/2/)

The content of first table is loading from database and sometimes users can enter 3 or 4 lines of text into td (that's why I can't declare table/tr/td height). Content of second table is always the same (there will be always one line of text)

Is it possible (with javascript/jquery), that table 2 somehow inherit table rows height from table 1 (if user enter longer text) and perfectly align like here: [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/4pdCq/3/) ?

I'm trying to do it like this but I have completely no idea how to check height of an element without declaring it in css first:

```
var tableH = $("#table1 tr").height();
$("#table2 tr").css("min-height", tableH);
```

Comment: Does it make any sense, semantically speaking, to merge cells from both table on the same line in a single tr row in one table?

Comment: In the fiddle, the empty lines are created in the HTML, separate from jQuery.

Comment: Mooseman they are created via jquery, and FelipaAls, it's just for user view. ALigned tables looks more esthetic

Comment: Are the number of rows in both tables same?

Comment: @Peeyush Kushwaha yes they are always the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets pretty close

```
var itemNum = 0;

$("#table1 tr").each(function() {
  $("#table2 tr:nth-child(" + (itemNum+1) + ")").height( $(this).height() );
  itemNum++;
});
```

**EDIT**

Added +1 to itemNum. `nth-child` is 1-based. Seems to work on your fiddle

**EDIT 2**

As per thirdender's suggestion, this can be simplified to

```
$("#table1 tr").each(function(itemNum) {
  $("#table2 tr:nth-child(" + (itemNum+1) + ")").height( $(this).height() );
});
```

Comment: jQuery's [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method passes the index in the array to the function callback, so you can leave out the `var itemNum = 0;` and just change `.each(function() {` to `.each(function(itemNum) {` instead.

Comment: @thirdender: Sweet! Thanks. Seems like I may have actually used that before, but had forgotten about it.

Answer (score 1):

Semantically, it makes sense to merge the tables. Here's some quick code that will do just that:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  var table2Rows = $("#table2 tr");
  $("#table1 tr").each(function(i) {
    table2Rows.eq(i).contents().appendTo(this);
  });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/thirdender/4pdCq/9/)**

If you're generating the tables using jQuery or server side code, it makes sense to do the merge then (if possible) instead of later (using this code).

Also, I noticed some of the cells in the second table are empty… I updated the code to make the cells from the first table stretch (increased `colspan`) to fill that empty space: [see updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thirdender/4pdCq/10/).

Also, I think semantically it would make even more sense to make each day's activities a separate TBODY: [see even more updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thirdender/4pdCq/12/) :-p

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
$('#table2 td').each(function () {
  $(this).height($($('#table1 td')[$(this).index()]).height());
});
```

(untested)

Answer (score 0):

I am curious why you are doing this with TR and trying to get the row height.

Depending on what technology you are using to get the data there will be some good ways to combine the data.  Is it coming across as JSON?

Maybe you can build it as fluid rows and use the spans to keep them aligned as you add records.

Also it will keep it from losing alignment as you add data.

http://jsfiddle.net/4pdCq/7/

I imported the bootstrap.css to make this work.

```
<div class="row-fluid rowBorder">
  <div class="span4">Subject</div>
  <div class="span2">Hour</div>
  <div class="span4">Users</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid rowBorder">
  <div class="span10">Monday</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid rowBorder">
  <div class="span4">English English English english english english</div>
  <div class="span2">3pm</div>
  <div class="span4">User1</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid rowBorder">
  <div class="span4">Espanol</div>
  <div class="span2">4pm</div>
  <div class="span4">User2</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid rowBorder">
  <div class="span10">Tuesday</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid rowBorder">
  <div class="span4">Italian</div>
  <div class="span2">1pm</div>
  <div class="span4">User3</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid rowBorder">
  <div class="span4">French</div>
  <div class="span2">2pm</div>
  <div class="span4">User4</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid rowBorder">
  <div class="span10">Wednesday</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid rowBorder">
  <div class="span4">Japanese</div>
  <div class="span2">10pm</div>
  <div class="span4">User5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: as I said , tables are loaded dynamically, I can't change them into divs

Comment: what are you using to load them dynamically?

Comment: Also, @zmanc, why bootstrap.css/`DIV`s instead of just a `TABLE`? This strikes me as [tabular data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.1): "text, preformatted text, images, links, forms, form fields, other tables, etc."

Comment: @thirdender, I suggested the use of div's instead of a table because each fluid row can be created dynamically as a separate object and using the span widths can keep everything aligned easily. Also being a fluid row he will not have to worry about columns scaling at different rates causing mis-alignments.